# Vimscript - Regex to match only open parentheses and not open/close pair

Tags: vim

In Vim Script, I'm trying to use regex to match a string that contains `(` and not `()` pair.

```
let s:OPEN_PAREN = '([^)]*'

echomsg 'Hello (' =~? s:OPEN_PAREN
echomsg '( Hello' =~? s:OPEN_PAREN
echomsg '(' =~? s:OPEN_PAREN
echomsg ')' =~? s:OPEN_PAREN
echomsg 'Hello (my text) test' =~? s:OPEN_PAREN
```

Result is `0` for all cases and not sure what is wrong with my regex and hoping someone can help me with this.

Comment: Try escaping the opening parenthese

Comment: Tried `'\([^)]*'` but that didn't work. Still getting `0` for all test cases

Comment: Using your example in `$ vim --clean` (two recent 9.0.XXXX builds), I get the expected `1`, `1`, `1`, `0`, and `1`. Tell us more about your setup.

Comment: Vim version `VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Apr 15 2023 04:26:05)`. I have `set nocompatible` in my `vimrc` and I have no plugins installed. I start vim without any arguments. Is there any specific you are looking for?

Comment: `/\(.*)\)\@!.*(.*` can do the job

Answer (score 0):

Here I provide the following 2 regex:

`/\(.*)\)\@!.*(.*`

`/.*(.*).*\n\zs\|.*(.*`

Best regards.